# Videos are green?

Tags: windows-10, video-playback

All of my videos are green on Windows 10. It doesn't matter if they are locally stored, streamed from YouTube, or played from DVD's; every video type imaginable I could test with is green.

It doesn't matter what program, or web browser I used (tried Edge, Chrome, and Firefox)—I get the same green video. I've also tested with Windows Media Player, and VLC Media Player with the same green result. I can hear audio just fine but all I see is green for the video.

I do NOT seem to have this issue with video games or pictures—I only have Minecraft installed so that's the game I tested with to confirm.

[image]

**Update:** Sorry for the lack of a reply. Things have been a bit hectic. I have gotten everything to work except Apps. Edge works, IE works, Chrome works. Just nothing else... Thanks for the help...The suggestions in the first answer have partially helped....

**Update 2:** Seems to work in VLC for Windows Store... But not Movies & TV

Comment: Sounds like you don't have the right graphics drivers installed. What exactly is your GPU and what exact version of the drivers have you installed?

Comment: have you tried my suggestion? Do you use an AMD GPU and Hyper-V?

Comment: I have not had time, busy weekend...I will let you know if this works or not.

Comment: any update on the issue?

Comment: Update on the OQ...

Comment: Which is the first question you mentioned? Did you mean the oldest or the top-voted one? Please include a link to it!

Answer (score 6):

> ### "All of my videos are green"

### [**Potential Solution 1**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-to-install-and-update-drivers-in-windows-10/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293)

> **Installing drivers through Windows Update** 
>   Windows Update is the
>   premier starting point to resolve most common driver issues you might
>   experience immediately after installing Windows 10.
>
> Simply launch it
>   from **Start** > **Settings** > **Update and Recovery** and click **Check for
>   Updates**
>
> or
>
> Press **Windows key** + **R** Type: **ms-settings:windowsupdate** Hit
>   **Enter** Click **Check for updates** (make sure you have an active Internet
>   connection).

### [**Potential Solution 2**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/wiki/insider_wintp-insider_devices/how-to-install-and-update-drivers-in-windows-10/a97bbbd1-9973-4d66-9a5b-291300006293)

> **Install drivers using Device Manager**
>
> If your driver was not detected or installed by **Windows Update**,
>   you can try installing the driver manually if you have a compatible
>   version. Windows 10 and previous versions of Windows such as Windows 7
>   share the same driver model, so it should work.
>
> Press **Windows key** + **X**
>
> Click **Device Manager**
>
> Once device manager is open, select the device, right click it and
>   click **Update Driver Software**
>
> This will launch the update driver software wizard, which presents two
>   options.
>
> - **Search automatically for updated driver software** - its possible Windows might have the driver software if you have not checked it yet.

### [**Potential Solution 3**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/video-streaming-problems-on-windows-10/3411a7c0-f234-45da-9c38-4d584264f119?page=30)

> My solution to the problem was to turn off Hardware Acceleration. 
>   Every application that I have had issues with, the moment I turn OFF
>   Hardware Acceleration, the applications runs smooth after that.   I'm
>   not sure what Windows 10 did that caused such an enormous amount of
>   headache with hardware acceleration, but it's definitely going to need
>   to be addressed.  Below are links to correct the issues in your
>   browser, however, you'll have to do the same in every application
>   where you experience issues.  Since I don't have the time to list out
>   the instructions for every application in the world, you'd have to
>   hunt and find that setting and disable it.  Hope this helps!
>
> - [**Removing Hardware Acceleration from Google Chrome**](http://www.solveyourtech.com/turn-hardware-acceleration-google-chrome/)
> - [**Removing Hardware Acceleration from Internet Explorer**](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2528233)
> - [**Removing Hardware Acceleration from Firefox**](http://www.askvg.com/how-to-disable-hardware-acceleration-gpu-rendering-in-mozilla-firefox-4-0-to-fix-font-problem/)

### [**Potential Solution 4**](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-hardware/video-streaming-problems-on-windows-10/3411a7c0-f234-45da-9c38-4d584264f119?page=30)

> Install
>   Firefox and install adobe flash plugin and flash pluting for your
>   tube.  Make sure edge is closed when you do this.  I now have sound in
>   my videos and in Netflix using Microsoft edge.  Thank you Microsoft
>   for wasting everyones time on this.  But this fix worked and you did
>   not suggest it.  I got this form a blog somewhere.

Comment: Sorry for the lack of a reply. Things have been a bit hectic. I have gotten everything to work except Apps.  

Edge works, IE works, Chrome works. Just nothing else...

Thanks for the help...your suggestions have partially helped....

Comment: Still green videos. Despite trouble shooting and installing videos. I have given up.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this in Windows 8 when you use an AMD GPU and have Hyper-V installed. If you have an AMD GPU and use Hyper-V, disable Hyper-V if you don't really need it.

Also disable HW acceleration in the programs options, this also seam to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/909554) official describtion from Microsoft Support about this problem.

A short summary about the possible solutions:

- **Make sure that you are using the latest drivers for the video card that are provided directly from the video card manufacturer or from the system manufacturer. If you update the drivers, make sure that the Color Quality setting in the Display Properties dialog box was not reset.**
- **Verify that you have any other software updates for the video card. Also, verify that you have the latest updates for Microsoft DirectX. For other software updates for the video card, and also for DirectX updates, visit the following Microsoft Web [site](http://update.microsoft.com).**
- **Turn down video acceleration. To do this in Microsoft Windows Media Player 9 Series or in later versions of Microsoft Windows Media Player, follow these steps:**

  > ```
  > 1.On the Tools menu, click Options. The Options dialog box appears.
  > 2.In the Options dialog box, click the Performance tab.
  > 3.In the Video acceleration area, move the slider to turn down or turn off video acceleration.
  > 4.Test to see whether the video will play back correctly.
  > ```
- **Change the advanced video acceleration settings. To do this in Windows Media Player 9 Series or in later versions of Windows Media Player, follow these steps:**

  > ```
  > 1.On the Tools menu, click Options. The Options dialog box appears.
  > 2.In the Options dialog box, click the Performance tab.
  > 3.In the Video acceleration area, click Advanced.
  > 4.In the Video Acceleration Settings dialog box, click to clear the check box for Use Overlays.
  > 5.Test to see whether the video will play back correctly. If the video does not play back correctly, and you are using Windows Media Player 10, go to step 6.
  > 6.In the Video Acceleration Settings dialog box, click to clear the check box for Use High Quality Mode.
  > 7.Test to see whether the video will play back correctly.
  > ```
- **Lower the screen resolution. To do this, follow these steps:**

  > ```
  > 1.Right-click the Microsoft Windows desktop, and then click Properties.
  > 2.In the Display Properties dialog box, click the Settings tab.
  > 3.In the Screen Resolution section, drag the slider to incrementally decrease the screen resolution.
  > 4.Test to see whether the video will play back correctly.
  > ```

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution to this problem on my machine. I'll tell you what I did, but it may not work for you. If you do not have a dgpu (not integrated graphics) this will not fix your problem, but for those who do, I hope I can help.

The fix for me was changing the "graphics performance preference" for the Movies & TV app. Open your display settings (open start menu and just type display settings and click the first option). Then scroll down and open "graphics settings." From there, change "Classic App" to "Universal App", and in the drop down window that appears select "Movies & TV", then press Add. Then click on the "Movies & TV" that appears, click "Options", and set the graphics preference to "High performance." Click "Save" and then you're done.

I hope this helps.