# Intel UHD Graphics 360 video not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, video, intel-graphics

I have a computer with an Intel Core i5-8600k and no GPU. I installed the driver for the Intel UHD Graphics 360 from the CD that came with the CPU on Windows 10.

Everything is working fine except for videos, which don't play at all. On YouTube it loads forever. On Netflix it shows a green screen. On VLC I can hear the audio but there is no video... I don't understand.

Also I have a dual-boot, and in Ubuntu 18.04 it all works. Could it be something with the codecs? If so, how can I install them?

Last thing - my Windows 10 isn't OEM. I downloaded the ISO from microsoft.com and I think the version was 1709. It's now 1803 and everything is up to date in Windows Update.

One more thing: I found something on another post about the same kind of problem and it said to disable hardware acceleration. I did it in Firefox and now it plays videos. I *really don't understand*.

Here is the post about the hardware acceleration: [Videos are green?](https://superuser.com/questions/1033491/videos-are-green)

Edit: Finally I just had to update my drivers from Intel website and it worked. Thanks for the comments.

Comment: I would install the latest video driver from the manufacturer of your PC, not the one on CD. this is a known issue with 1803 update and some video drivers.......https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+10+1803+green+video&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS771US771&oq=windows+10+1803+green+video&aqs=chrome..69i57.7855j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: @Moab Thanks for your answer, the problem was the outdated driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what the problem was: The graphic drivers on my DVD weren't enough up to date, I just had to download them from the intel website and it instantly worked, before I even rebooted.